# Possible multiplicity issues in equivalence testing

Tags: bonferroni, equivalence, tost, multiplicity

I'm currently looking to compare 3 groups, trying to prove equivalence between them. For this, 5 specific parameters are measured for each group, and a pairwise comparison for each parameter among the 3 groups is performed. When equivalence between the 3 groups for each of the 5 parameters is shown, equivalence between the 3 groups can be assumed.

For showing equivalence, I'm looking to use the TOST equivalence test, applied as a pairwise comparison. Since this means multiple testing among the same sample, I'm concerned about alpha risk inflation. Same goes for basing the overall equivalence on the results of multiple TOST equivalence tests.

For ANOVA tests, multiplicity testing issues are pretty well discussed and explained. However, for equivalence tests, this is not the case. I've found several sources talking about the issue; however, to me it seems that many of the contradict themselves. For example, [Berger et al](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1032280304) talks about how if all individual tests are performed at level-alpha, the overall test is also at level alpha (see p.6, "Theorem 1" of his paper). Other authors however constructed Bonferroni-like corrections to the alpha-level of the individual tests in order to keep the overall test at a certain level alpha (for example [Lauzon et al (p.4 equation 6)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2800314/) ). [Some](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263671284_Multiplicity_adjustments_in_testing_for_bioequivalence) even seem to mix the two approaches, first saying that multiplicity is not a issue for equivalence tests, then developing methods to solve these issues.

So, which corrections, if any, do I have to make to prove equivalence for my 3 groups through all of my 5 parameters at an overall level alpha risk?

I know that I'm clearly missing some major point that would explain all this, but no matter how much I read on the topic or who I discuss it with, I'm not really getting it.

All help is highly appreciated, thank you all!!

Comment: What is needed is a precise definition of the error probability you want to control. Are you saying you want a max. $\alpha$ probability of not accepting non-equivalence if indeed any kind of non-equivalence holds?

Answer (score 0):

The issue addressed by Berger and others is for the IUT method. If you could set up your problem accordingly, then you are free of multiplicity correction. However, most of the times this is not the case.

Let's start with recalling what $\alpha$ is: the probability, under the null assumption, of mistakenly rejecting the null hypothesis in favor of a powerful alternative. We'll get to this definition a bit later.

What is the IUT method anyway? Consider the unknown parameter $\theta$ (either scalar or vector) and the parameter space $\Theta$. $\Theta$ has subsets $\Theta_1,...,\Theta_k$, each having a complement $\Theta_1^C,...,\Theta_k^C$. The IUT method has the following hypotheses:

$$H_0:\theta \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}\Theta_i, \quad H_1:\theta \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{k}\Theta_i^C$$

(hence the intersection-union method name). The idea is this: we have a set of $k$ level-$\alpha$ tests, each with hypotheses $H_{0i}:\theta\in\Theta_i,\quad H_{1i}:\theta\in\Theta_i^C$. Now, under $H_{0i}$, if $\theta\in\Theta_i$ then the probability of mistakenly rejecting $H_{0i}$ in favor of $H_{1i}$ is $\alpha$. That's trivial. The other thing here is also trivial, albeit more tricky: $\theta$ could be at most in one of $\Theta_1,...,\Theta_k$. That is, under each of the null hypotheses $H_{0i}$, if $\theta\in\Theta_i$ then it is by definition, **not** in $\Theta_j,\quad j\in\{1,...,k\}/\{i\}$. The meaning is that the probability of rejecting all other null hypotheses (in favor of their alternatives) is 1, therefore the product of the rejection probabilities is by definition $(1)^{k-1}\cdot\alpha$.

---

If you're able to divide your 5-dimensional parameter space into subsections, as described, then maybe you could use the IUT method and avoid multiplicity correction. In my experience with equivalence testing, it's not so convenient. I can suggest you two options here, which you can use:

1. Creating a vector of the parameters, then comparing one vector against the other (that's three comparisons overall). You can do it using some norm $d$ that you like and define the null (non-equivalence) hypothesis to be $H_0:d\ge\lambda$. If you have any way to assume the parameters are coming from a multivariate distribution (e.g. regression coefficients) then Some handy results are waiting - the test statistic using Mahalanobis distance (based on the pooled covariance matrix) has a non-central $\chi^2$ distribution. For more details, see Section 2.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.13330).
2. Testing for the ratio of a pair of parameter estimates (e.g. $p_1$ in groups $A,B$). This is very similar to bioequivalence testing and could be further explained in literature, for example [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10543400903105299).

Even if you do end up doing 15 pairwise comparisons (which might be the easiest option), there are alternatives to the Bonferroni method (which is harshly conservative). To ensure level $\alpha$ for the global test, you will want to keep what's called FWER (familywise error rate) under $\alpha$. A very handy method would be [the Holm method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method).